# Why is my handheld device visible to/in Windows Explorer, but claims not be connected?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, windows-explorer, activesync, mobile-devices

My normal process when making changes to the Windows CE / Compact Framework project I'm working on is to build it in Visual Studio on my Windows 7 machine, then copy the exe to the appropriate folder on the handheld device via Windows Explorer.

Friday and today, though, when I try to first delete the old version of the .exe in Explorer, I get, "*ERROR DELETING FILE. Platypus.exe could not be deleted. The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected.*"

Then the "Deleting..." dialog displays forever and a day (until I mash the "Cancel" button).

According to Windows Explorer, the handheld device is connected, for how else would I be able to see the file there? Yet Explorer then says it is not responding or has been disconnected...???

A big clue about this is probably that formerly when starting up, the computer would show the big green Active Sync dialog box, from which I would "connect without configuring" or some such. Now I no longer see that dialog. I did not uninstall or otherwise molest Active Sync. How can I revivify it? Should I reinstall it, or...???

I can select "Windows Mobile Device Center" from the Start menu. It says "Connected", Last sync: today. Under "Mobile Device Settings" I have all of these checked:

```
Allow USB connections (the handheld device (Motorola/Symbol 3190) is plugged into a USB port on the computer)
Allow connections to one of the following - Bluetooth (other options are COM1 and DMA)
All automatic device authentication - and the "This computer is connected to:" is set to: Automatic
```

I selected "Windows Mobile Device Center" in the Control Panel and selected "Repair" - it made no difference - I still get the same err msg on trying to delete the old .exe that I need to replace.

### UPDATE

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931937, if "Microsoft Windows Mobile Remote Adapter" is not present, "Disconnect and then reconnect your device. Your device driver will be reinstalled"

Not so - actually, I'm connected, it seems, but if I try to delete one of the files on the device from Windows Explorer, I get, "*Platypus.exe could not be deleted. The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected.*"

When I try the "Device is disconnected when syncing large files" portion of that link, and make sure that the "USB Cable" connection settings are set to the handheld's IP Address (which I sussed out using ipconfig at the command line), with the "Specify and IP address" radio button selected, it makes no difference/doesn't help.

I changed to the "Obtain an IP address via DHCP" radio button, and that, too, changes nothing. Besides, it doesn't "take," because when I go back and look at it, it has switched back to "Specify an IP address"...???

Note: Windows Mobile Device Center no longer comes up on starting the desktop machine, rebooting, or undocking/redocking the handheld device; I can only get it to display when I select it explicitly from the Start > All Programs menu.

It says my device (MC3190A) is connected, and yet it only "half" acts like it is...Windows Explorer on the desktop acts like the files it sees on the handheld device are read-only (I can see them and select them, but all attempts to delete a file fail).

### UPDATE 2

Also, doubtless related to these problems I'm having, when I try to run the "Active Sync Remote Display" utility on my desktop, I get, "Remote Display for Windows CE - Can not detect ActiveSync connection"

Comment: It seems cliché, but have you restarted the PC and the device?

Comment: Yes, but I'll try it again, just for Nils Lofgrins.

Comment: Still nothing; it refuses to delete the file.

Comment: Somehow the "and the device" part of that question got filtered out in my brain. A warm boot of the device solved the dilemma.